# Set value based on drop down selection using script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Because prices change over time, I don't want to tie in the price permanently to another cell. So I'd like the script to set the price based on drop down selection.

I have `Services` sheet with `Cost` column:
[image]

I'd like the script to apply the cost based on selection like so (in `Selection` sheet):
[image]

Here's the example spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=232108540

How can I set value `Cost` in `Services` sheet to `Selection` sheet with script?

Comment: Why not just use a VLOOKUP, as a lookup of the selected service in the Selection sheet to the cost sheet, like so - `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Services!A:B,2,FALSE),0)`?

Comment: I don't want to permanently tie the cost value to a cell since the cost can change over time, and I want to keep historical pricing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function cost() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Services');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var costObj={}
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    costObj[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
  }
  var selsh=ss.getSheetByName('Selection');
  var selrg=selsh.getRange(2,1,selsh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vB=selrg.getValues();
  for(var j=0;j<vB.length;j++) {
    vB[j][1]=costObj[vB[j][0]];
  }
  selrg.setValues(vB);
  //if you only want to set columnB you can do this instead of the above line
  //var vC=vB.map(function(r){return [r[1]]});
  //selsh.getRange(2,2,vC.length,1).setValues(vC);
}
```

As an onEdit():

```
function cost(e) {//Installable onEdit()
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name!='Selection')return;
  if(e.value && e.range.columnStart==1) {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(getCostObj()[e.value]);
  }
}  
function getCostObj() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Services');
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,2);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var costObj={}
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    costObj[vA[i][0]]=vA[i][1];
  }
  return costObj;
}
```

Comment: This only adds cost value once we execute the script, we can simply change it to `onEdit`?

Comment: It probably would be better to do it as a cell function as @Joshua T suggested. I think that we tend to use onEdit way too much.

Comment: but that wouldn't keep historical pricing if prices change, and I'd like to keep historical pricing? can we make the script so that it's efficient with `onEdit`, it looks like this script scans entire column and adds script, which may be inefficient for the `onEdit` needs

Comment: Okay.  What user action initiates the onEdit() event? What Cell? What Column? ...

Comment: On `Selection` sheet, on column `A` drop down, it should set `Cost` on column `B`, the cell next to the drop down

Comment: I suspect this will have to be an installable trigger.

Comment: Looks like there's quite a few things that are incorrect, from `cost` function, the `getCostObj[e.value]` should be `getCostObj([e.value])` and function `getCostObj()` should be `getCostObj(e)`

Comment: No getCostObj() doesn't get triggered.  It get's called. getCostObj()[e.value] is correct.  Cost(e) get's triggered and it calls getCostObj();

Comment: I had this line incorrect `e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(getCostObj[e.value]);` and I corrected it to this `e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(getCostObj()[e.value]);`